# make ansible check if database is present on a remote host

Tags: mysql, ansible

To make sure that host A can connect to the database of the host B, I try to use mysql_db on a remote host

```
- name: Make sure A can connect to B database
  mysql_db:
    login_user=root
    login_password=password
    login_host=B_address
    login_port=B_port
    name=B_database
    state=present
```

and I get that error message even if the login/pass is right

```
msg: unable to connect, check login_user and login_password are correct, 
or alternatively check ~/.my.cnf contains credentials
```

Am i missing something? can I set login_host with a specific ansible host?

Comment: If you're on Rails and you need to initialize the database then `rails db:prepare` creates, seeds, and migrates the database in an idempotent way (i.e. if it already exists then it only migrates it).

Answer (score 7):

In my situation I only wanted to import an SQL file once, when the database gets created. Here's how to achieve that, the Ansible way:

```
---
- name: Test playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Database exists
      mysql_db:
        name: some_db
        state: present
      register: database_exists
    - name: Import database schema
      mysql_db:
        name: some_db
        state: import
        target: database.sql.gz
      when: database_exists.changed
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    Did you configure the mysql to accept the connection from Host A because 
by default mysql only accept connection from localhost.
```

If you have configured that the mysql accept the connection from Host A then you can verify that the database exist

```
- name: check if DB exists
   shell: mysql -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' | grep {{ B_database }}
   register: dbstatus
   failed_when: dbstatus.rc == 2
```

Then you can run your task, if the B_database exist

```
- name: Make sure A can connect to B database
  mysql_db:
    login_user=root
    login_password=password
    login_host=B_address
    login_port=B_port
    name=B_database
    state=present
  when: dbstatus.rc == 0 
  no_log: yes # You can disable this, if you want to print the stdout
```

If you are sure that the above cases are true and you are still getting error, then please do this:

Add this task inside your task/main.yml

```
- name: Copy the root credentials as .my.cnf file
   template:
     src: root.cnf.j2
     dest: "~/.my.cnf"
     mode: 0600
```

and this will be your root.cnf.j2

```
[client]
user=root
password={{ password }}
```

What it will do is, to connect the mysql from the root user without password and perform these task. You can remove it after running all the task or leave it like this because it is under root and have tight permission.

Comment: When the database doesn't exist `grep` will return exit code 1 which will cause the task to fail. You need to add `failed_when: dbstatus.rc == 2` to only fail the task if `grep` reports an actual error (exit code 2) instead of no results found (exit code 1). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34345705/857390).

Comment: @FlorianBrucker Thanks for the tips

Comment: Beware that you **also** get exit code 1, rather than 2, as you perhaps might expect, with an *Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost'* error when the DB definitely *does* exist, but the credentials are invalid.

Comment: no_log: true <- use this to hide password. 

don't print passwords to stdout !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using combination of above answers

```
- name: check if DB exists
  shell: mysql --host={{ db_host }} --user={{ db_username }} --password={{ db_password }} -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' | grep -c {{ db_name }}
  register: dbstatus
  failed_when: dbstatus.rc == 2

- name: Create database
  mysql_db: name={{db_name}} collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci state=present login_host={{ db_host }} login_user={{ db_root_username }} login_password={{ db_root_password }}
  when: dbstatus.stdout == "0"

- name: Create application user in the database
  mysql_user: name={{ db_username }} password={{ db_password }} host={{ db_connection_host }} append_privs=true priv={{ db_name }}.*:ALL state=present login_host={{ db_host }} login_user={{ db_root_username }} login_password={{ db_root_password }}
  when: dbstatus.stdout == "0"
```

useful to note you can get the output of dbstatus by adding -vvv when you run the playbook

Answer (score 1):

Because ansible was failing on the grep exit code when it was not found, I found a different way to filter the databases:

```
> mysql -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '<database>'" -sN
```

and then you can do the following:

```
  when: dbstatus.stdout_lines
```

because python will treat an empty array as `false`

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that there's actually 3 hosts involved here:

- the "ansible execution host", the host on which you're running ansible;
- the "ansible target host", the host(s) your task target;
- the mysql host, that is the databse server.

In this case, the target host needs to be able to connect to the mysql host as the login_user with the login_password.

Check :

- that the provider user and password are granted connectivity to the mysql host from the target host
- that the firewalls between the target and mysql hosts allow mysql connections (typically port 3306).  If these things work, so should the ansible module.

Answer (score 0):

Use config_file: to connect, and check mode to figure out if database exists or not:

```
- name: Make sure A can connect to B database
  mysql_db:
    config_file: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
    name=B_database
    state=present
  check_mode: yes
  register: database_exists

- debug: var=database_exists.changed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with postgresql and a much later version of ansible, so using the above answers I pulled together this solution.

```
 - name: find out if db exists
   postgresql_query:
     query: |
       SELECT datname FROM pg_database where datname = '{{ dbname }}'
   register: result
   become: yes
   become_user: postgres

 - name: look at results {{ result.rowcount }}..... 
   debug:
     var: result
```

`{{ dbname }}` is a variable which can be replaced with a literal. The second task shows that you can look at the result.rowcount and if it is 0 then the database does not exist. If it is 1, the database exist. Now you can use result.rowcount with when: to determine if a task is executed or not. For example, in my case I'm trying to determine if I should create the database or not, such as:

```
 - name: message if db exists....
   debug:
     msg: "yes it exist"
   when: "{{ result.rowcount }} == 1"
```