# Evaluating return code in ansible conditional

Tags: ansible

I'm working on automating a task which needs to append the latest version of software to a file. I don't want it to do this multiple times for the same version.

It looks at the following example file:

```
var software releases = new Array(
    "4.3.0",
    "4.4.0",
    "4.5.0",
    "4.7.0",
    "4.8.0",
    "4.11.0",
    "4.12.1",
    "4.14.0",
    "4.15.0",
    "4.16.0",
);
```

the defaults main.yml would pass in something like

```
VERSION: 4.16.2
```

code

```
- name: register version check
  shell: cat /root/versions.js | grep -q {{VERSION}}
  register: current_version

- debug: msg="The registered variable output is {{ current_version.rc }}"

- name: append to versions.js
  lineinfile:
    dest: /root/versions.js
    regexp: '^\);'
    insertbefore: '^#\);'
    line: "    \"{{VERSION}}\",\n);"
    owner: root
    state: present
    when: current_version.rc == 1
```

problem: the debug message is evaluating current_version.rc and showing me boolean values based on the grep commands output, but I can't re-use this in the `when` conditional to determine if the task should be run.

Edit: the output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [test | register version check] *****************************************
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cat /root/versions.js | grep -q 3.19.2", "delta": "0:00:00.003570", "end": "2015-12-17 00:24:49.729078", "rc": 1, "start": "2015-12-17 00:24:49.725508", "warnings": []}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/site.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the play?

Comment: You're not getting to the when statement, because the return code is 1. Add 'ignore_errors: True'.

Comment: nikobelia - this solved my problem! Feel free to answer this so I can mark it if you'd like.  Thanks.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As [nikobelia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3276583/nikobelia) pointed out in the comments, [`grep` returns an exit code of 1 when it doesn't match any lines](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html). Ansible then interprets this (actually any status code other than 0 from a shell/command task) as an error and so promptly fails.

You can tell Ansible to ignore the response code from the shell/command task by using [`ignore_errors`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands). Although with `grep` this will ignore actual errors (given by a return code of 2) so instead you might want to use [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) like this:

```
- name: register version check
  shell: cat /root/versions.js | grep -q {{VERSION}}
  register: current_version
  failed_when: current_version.rc == 2
```

Comment: Yes, for completion you can also use : `failed_when: ( result.rc not in [ 0, 1 ] )`

Comment: or even `result.rc > 1` …

Comment: I found this doesn't work in some older ansible versions e.g. 2.10.6 so beware.